# de.laures.cewolf - IIOException: Can't create output stream

Tags: java, tomcat, cewolf

I know it's a long shot ass there's very little to go on, but would anyone have any clues as to what would cause this exception with Cewolf image rendering?

I'm wondering if there are anny specific locations/paths/folders or permissions that cewolf is expecting.

**localhost.log**

```
de.laures.cewolf.util.Renderer.renderChart
```

**system-err.log**

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't create output stream

SEVERE: CewolfServlet: Can't create output stream!
de.laures.cewolf.ChartRenderingException: Can't create output stream!
    at de.laures.cewolf.util.Renderer.renderChart(Renderer.java:120)
...

Caused by: javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't create output stream!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1560)
    at org.jfree.chart.encoders.SunPNGEncoderAdapter.encode(SunPNGEncoderAdapter.java:128)
    at org.jfree.chart.encoders.EncoderUtil.writeBufferedImage(EncoderUtil.java:137)
    at org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(ChartUtilities.java:176)
    at de.laures.cewolf.util.Renderer.handlePNG(Renderer.java:142)
    at de.laures.cewolf.util.Renderer.renderChart(Renderer.java:108)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't create cache file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(ImageIO.java:397)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1558)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(File.java:1705)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile0(File.java:1726)
    at java.io.File.access$100(File.java:120)
    at java.io.File$1.createTempFile(File.java:1955)
    at sun.misc.IOUtils.createTempFile(IOUtils.java:88)
    at javax.imageio.stream.FileCacheImageOutputStream.<init>(FileCacheImageOutputStream.java:71)
    at com.sun.imageio.spi.OutputStreamImageOutputStreamSpi.createOutputStreamInstance(OutputStreamImageOutputStreamSpi.java:50)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(ImageIO.java:393)
    ... 43 more
26-Sep-2013 03:38:26 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
```

This is working on my machine but not on a new machine I have just been setting up, but I did not do anything different.

Cheers in advance

KS

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the application try to output to a directory that does not exists based on:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
```

Hope it helps you forward.

**EDIT** 
Oh, I see now you wonder where that path migh be. Can't help you there. I would assume it's set in the servlet.